# TiledGame, how to check near surround blocks for collision?

Tags: java, 2d, collision, tile

I'm trying to develop a Tiled 2D game in Java. The map is a grid, where all tiles have a size of 48x48 (so does the player).

I do not want to loop through all tiles from the map to check if the player is colliding. I'm trying to make the player to only check the nearest blocks, for every movement he makes, based on a "solid" boolean flag from the block.

The issue that I'm facing is: the player moves freely. He can be between 2 blocks.

How can I implement this method based on block size, player position and surrounding index?

[Scenario Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceqtv.png)

This is the closest I could get:

```
public void checkCollisionWhenMoving() {
   for (int i = (player.y / 48) - 2; i <= 4; i++) {
        for (int j = (player.y / 48)  - 2; j <= 4; ++j) {
            if (blocksMap[i][j].isBlocked()) {
                collisionDetector.checkCollision(player.getCollisionBox(),
                        blocksMap[i][j].getCollisionBox());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to actually think of the collision itself (AABB collision etc), just how to loop the collision method for all the near surrouding blocks.

If you need any more code, let me know.

Comment: One Idea would be to check if the next movement is valid. Lets say he moves to pos 67/5. calculate the tile: 1/0. if 1/0 is a floor tile, let him move. if not, dont (or let him move as far to the border as possible). Other approach: Check player position in every frame if it is on valid tile. Same calculation. If not, set him to the last valid position.

Comment: @Eskalior thanks for answering! I did not quiet get your first approach... about the second one, how do I check if the player is on a valid tile bearing in mind that the player is moving pixel by pixel, and the coordinates (x,y) of each tile jumps from 48 and 48, and so on. He can be in between tiles. Your approach works really well on a roguelike game where the player moves from block to block.

Comment: Lets say he is on position x: 90, y : 52. To get the tile he is on, just calculate: 90/48, 52/48 and floor it( round down). You get tile 1/1. Then you check blocksMap[1][1].isBlocked() and if true, the player is on an invalid tile.
Same calculation in the first approach. Just replace the players location with the desired location.

Comment: I got it now. Just realised that the "surrouding area" I was thinking at first won't work because if the player is at (0,0), there will be no tile on his top and left. I'll try to sort things out. Thanks!